# How to sorting two string arrays

Tags: java, sorting

I have two arrays:

```
arrayA = {"b","c","a"} 
arrayB = {"99","11","22"}
```

How do I sort them together so that `arrayA = {"a","b","c"}` and `arrayB = {"22","99","11"}`?

Comment: i think as you have C1, C2 .. the first characters stay the same. so instead of testing first character you can run a test on the seconds. which'll sort you the array.

Comment: java.util.Arrays.sort(arrayA);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made one alphanumeric sorting programm Check it out.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class AlphanumericSorting implements Comparator {
    public int compare(Object firstObjToCompare, Object secondObjToCompare) {
        String firstString = firstObjToCompare.toString();
        String secondString = secondObjToCompare.toString();

        if (secondString == null || firstString == null) {
            return 0;
        }

        int lengthFirstStr = firstString.length();
        int lengthSecondStr = secondString.length();

        int index1 = 0;
        int index2 = 0;

        while (index1 < lengthFirstStr && index2 < lengthSecondStr) {
            char ch1 = firstString.charAt(index1);
            char ch2 = secondString.charAt(index2);

            char[] space1 = new char[lengthFirstStr];
            char[] space2 = new char[lengthSecondStr];

            int loc1 = 0;
            int loc2 = 0;

            do {
                space1[loc1++] = ch1;
                index1++;

                if (index1 < lengthFirstStr) {
                    ch1 = firstString.charAt(index1);
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            } while (Character.isDigit(ch1) == Character.isDigit(space1[0]));

            do {
                space2[loc2++] = ch2;
                index2++;

                if (index2 < lengthSecondStr) {
                    ch2 = secondString.charAt(index2);
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            } while (Character.isDigit(ch2) == Character.isDigit(space2[0]));

            String str1 = new String(space1);
            String str2 = new String(space2);

            int result;

            if (Character.isDigit(space1[0]) && Character.isDigit(space2[0])) {
                Integer firstNumberToCompare = new Integer(Integer
                        .parseInt(str1.trim()));
                Integer secondNumberToCompare = new Integer(Integer
                        .parseInt(str2.trim()));
                result = firstNumberToCompare.compareTo(secondNumberToCompare);
            } else {
                result = str1.compareTo(str2);
            }

            if (result != 0) {
                return result;
            }
        }
        return lengthFirstStr - lengthSecondStr;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] alphaNumericStringArray = new String[] { "NUM10071",
                "NUM9999", "9997", "9998", "9996", "9996F" };

        Arrays.sort(alphaNumericStringArray, new AlphanumericSorting());

        for (int i = 0; i < alphaNumericStringArray.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(alphaNumericStringArray[i]);
        }

    }

}
```

**Here is the output:**

9996
9996F
9997
9998
NUM9999
NUM10071

Answer (score 1):

Use `Arrays.sort(arrayB)`. You can even supply your custom `Comparator` to affect the sorting.

Answer (score 0):

This link will help you Try array.sort(Arg);
http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/data/arrays/70sorting.html

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
Arrays.sort(arrayB);
```

Output is

```
C1
C2
C3



  arrayB = {"22","99","11"}
  Arrays.sort(arrayB);
```

Output:

```
11
22
99
```

Answer (score 0):

If you will be using the same letters and only 1 digit from 0 to 9, then, you can sort it in the same manner you have sorted the first array. If you intend to throw in more letters with more numbers, you will have to implement your own custom comparator (assuming the default behaviour does not suit you).

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question as written seems so obvious that I think we are not understanding what you are really asking.

I'm guessing that what you are really asking is how to sort one array, and reorder the second array based on how the sort reordered the first array.  (Your example is poorly chosen to illustrate this ... but it does in fact doing this.)

Assuming that's what you mean, the simplest way to do this is to turn the two arrays into a single array of pairs, sort the pairs based on the first field, and then use the sorted pair list to repopulate the original arrays.

The (possible) snag is that the total ordering of the second array is indeterminate if the sort is not stable.  (Or to put it another way, if there are duplicates in `arrayA`, then the relative order of the corresponding `arrayB` elements cannot be predicted.)  There are ways to deal with this.